# Getting JSON Data into image format

Tags: node.js, google-maps

I have this GET request I built to call Google APIS dot com to get an image of a house at a given address. It's all working fine. In Postman it displays the image from the body of the request. All good!

I converted the code to NodeJS REQUEST. Put that code into my project. It all works though the data returned is all `�����JFIF������` like this in the BODY returned.

Can you point me to some resources or can you tell me in NODEJS how I get that into a Image type variable. I want to then display it using JSON code into Messenger Bot. I have the JSON code to send a IMAGE type back to Messenger - I just need to get the results of the GET above into a format in NODEJS that will work - like a PNG or JPG format.

This is the code I used from Postman CODE:

```
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview',
  qs: 
   { size: '450x450',
     location: 'N108W15303%20Bel%20Aire%20Ln%2053022',
     fov: '90',
     heading: '235',
     pitch: '10',
     key: 'xxx' },
  headers: 
   { 'Postman-Token': 'xxx',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     Accept: 'application/json' } };

requestGoogle(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

The BODY var is is all `����JFIF��C`

It displays great in the Postman App. so you are somehow converting it to display it - what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated - or direct me to a resource that can help that would be great.

Comment: This looks like binary data being returned, i ran into this before and will look to see how I solved it.

Comment: Did you try using body inside image tag: <img src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&amp;location=eiffel%20tower,%20paris,%20france&amp;heading=-45&amp;pitch=42&amp;fov=110" border="1px">                    Refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview or https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/

Comment: I have not since this is not being served up for display.  Using nodejs to get image and then display inside Messenger.

Comment: Just found this - this is exactly what I am getting back as far as the weird characters.  It says here it's returning a JPG which makes sense.  If you were to put the URL in browser you get back a streetview.jpg.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575008/node-js-weird-encoding-on-response